# Returning $this after observer

Tags: programming, event-observer, best-practice

I see some conflicting information on the internet and in 3rd party modules alike - is it a requirement or best practice to return `$this` at the end of an observer method?

E.g.:

**MyCompany_Module_Model_Observer.php**

```
public function salesOrderSaveAfter($observer){
    //do stuff
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The core always `return $this;` in the context of observer methods - but there doesn't actually appear to be a reason for it.

Tracing back through `dispatchEvent()` you'll find the main method that calls observer methods (in `./app/Core/Model/App.php`)

```
protected function _callObserverMethod($object, $method, $observer)
{
    if (method_exists($object, $method)) {
        $object->$method($observer);
    } elseif (Mage::getIsDeveloperMode()) {
        Mage::throwException('Method "'.$method.'" is not defined in "'.get_class($object).'"');
    }
    return $this;
}
```

But at no point is the return value ever actually used or referenced to be passed into another observer down the chain.

Perhaps Magento were thinking longer term to use it as some means to retain/pass data within `$this` class instance outside of using sessions/registry; or it could have been legacy code that has just *stuck*.

I can't see a compelling reason to `return $this` - but that being said, if they do it in the core, that's what we do.

As a general rule, whatever the core does - we deem best practice. *With the exception of the shocking spelling mistakes* :)

Comment: "Ukringlish" :-)

Comment: I am ashamed to admit that I sometimes return $observer to get rid of IDE warning of unused parameter...

Comment: @Daniel - just don't add the param in the observer signature. PHP doesn't mind. But then again, the passed param might be needed in the future.

Answer (score 8):

$this (pun intended) is called a fluent interface.  It allows you to call multiple methods within an object without having refer back to a defined variable.

Comment: Thank you - I understand fluent interfaces. I'm looking for a compelling reason to return `$this` when there is  really no use for fluent interfaces on observers.

Comment: @Kevin - You don't need a fluent interface in Mage's observers. Not that I know of.

Answer (score 5):

It's just a Magento convention to always return `$this` instead of `void` (nothing) if a method has no other return value, regardless of it actually being used for a fluent interface anywhere or not.

The advantage is, that you don't need to think about if it's useful or not, and a superfluous fluent interface is better than a missing one. Also, Magento *might* start using them for observers, even though this is highly unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Some years later ... :)

> The core always return $this; in the context of observer methods -  [...]

or

> It's just a Magento convention to always return $this instead of void (nothing) if a method has no other return value [...]

No really. Just checked some observers in 1.9.3.x and many return nothing (`void`). So it's not really clear "what core code does" ;)

I've used `$return $this;` in my code too, but today - there will be no changes in M1 code - I'd leave it. I think - if I read others code - a `void` method is more clear then one with a blindly added `return $this`, that is never used.

---

**Edit:**

If using Aoe_Scheduler you can also return a `string` or `array` to display it in cron history.

[image]

Can't find any docs for this features ... related code here: https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler/blob/master/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php#L229-L259